# Transcribe addon multi language bug

Tags: structure, transcribe, multi-language

I am using ExpressionEngine-5.4.0 with Transcribe v3.6 & Structure v4.7

In my site there is 3 languages (Azerbaijani, English, Russian)

And this is my settings for per language

- Azerbaijani: no prefix, default language
- English: /en/ prefix
- Russian: /ru/ prefix

Homepage urls:

- /en/welcome (EN Home)
- /ru/welcome (RU Home)
- /xos-gelmisiniz  (AZ Home)

If the user's on site language is en or ru and if he types /xos-gelmisiniz to bar  ExpressionEngine returns 404 page.

**However**

If user types /az/xos-gelmisiz on browser bar will work. Doesn't matter what language was on that time.

How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These sound like issues that are specific to Structure and Transcribe rather than EE itself; have you tried asking for support from [eeharbour / packettide](https://eeharbor.com/) (who are authors of both add-ons)?

Comment: we are waiting response from eeharbour

Comment: I don't want to debugging and changing plugin core. If there is a simple way i want to use that way first